# How can I use relaimpo with glm?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm, importance

I want to examine the relative importance of the predictors in my model.

I know the `{relaimpo}` package in R allows for the examination of relative importance for `lm` but my model a `glm` and doesn't have a Gaussian family.

Is there a package that I can use to examine relative importance in this situation?

Take for example the following `glm`:

```
glm(hp ~ vs + am + disp, family=poisson(), data=mtcars)
```

Is there a method that would allow me to examine the relative importance of the three predictors in this model either using `{relaimpo}` or some other software implementation?

Comment: Your `glm` has no specified `family` and the default is `gaussian`. So it's a gaussian glm and works with `calc.relimp`. For other families, an error will be given, as the help file for `calc.relimp` states: "Objects of class mlm or glm with link functions other than identity or family other than gaussian lead to an error message."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the package `{domir}` on CRAN can accommodate a `glm`.

GLM does not have an explained variance metric in quite the same way as `lm` but you can obtain a very similar result (i.e., an "lmg"-type metric) from it using the `{pscl}` package's `pR2` function such as:

```
> domir::domin(hp ~ vs + am + disp, glm, list(pscl::pR2, "McFadden"), data = mtcars, family = poisson())
Overall Fit Statistic:      0.5997781 

General Dominance Statistics:
     General_Dominance Standardized Ranks
vs          0.24878939   0.41480242     2
am          0.03508896   0.05850324     3
disp        0.31589971   0.52669434     1

Conditional Dominance Statistics:
         IVs: 1     IVs: 2     IVs: 3
vs   0.46514343 0.24708946 0.03413528
am   0.05091885 0.03338903 0.02095901
disp 0.51211049 0.31419978 0.12138886

Complete Dominance Statistics:
           Dmned?vs Dmned?am Dmned?disp
Dmate?vs          0        1         -1
Dmate?am         -1        0         -1
Dmate?disp        1        1          0
```

The "General Dominance Statistics" produced by `domir::domin` are identical to `relaimpo::calc.relimp`'s "lmg" type (see [github](https://github.com/jluchman/domir) page for an illustration).